# How to change telerik WPF RadGridView column filtering view template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid

We are using telerik controls in our project. I want to change telerik Radgrid view's (For WPF) filtering view.

As of now it looks like this as shown below:

[image: Telerik WPF RadGridView Column filtering view]

And I want to change the text being show to actual color, so that it looks more realistic for the user to filter. Something like this:

[image: Color to be shown in filtering view in place of text]

How to get hold of the template of filtering view and inject the color rectangle there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get hold of the template of filtering view and inject the color rectangle there.

The ControlTemplate can be found in Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="FilteringControlTemplate" TargetType="grid:FilteringControl">
...
```

I customized the ItemTemplate (for the Office2013 theme) to achieve the following, which should give you an indication of what needs to be done. You could also have a look at the [CustomFilterControl](https://github.com/telerik/xaml-sdk/tree/master/GridView/CustomFilterControl) example.

[image]

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <CheckBox
        Content=""
        FontSize="13"
        Grid.Column="0"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      <Rectangle
        Fill="{Binding ConvertedValue, Converter={StaticResource DistinctValueConverter}}"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Height="16"
        Width="30" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please guide me how to download this code.

Comment: After installing UI for WPF, you will find the folders Binaries, Binaries.NoXaml and Themes Implicit in your installation folder (usually C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for WPF [version]\). Locate the Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml file in the appropriate folder.

Comment: Yea that I know, I was talking about the code project for which you have given the link. It was taking me to a Git url.

Comment: I have another question here, if I will change the template like this, it will be applied for all the columns right ? what should I do to apply it just to the column which is having color. Actually i am using RadColorPicker in the column which will be having color. Can I swap visibility on the basis of that somehow.

Comment: To download the Telerik example code, you need either a Git client to clone the repository or you can go to the front page of the repository, ,https://github.com/telerik/xaml-sdk, and click the "Download ZIP" button.

Comment: Yes, if you make changes  to the Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml it will be applied to all GridView controls. Extract the relevant styling to your own view/resource and specify that your GridView should use this styling. Yes, you should be able to make it work with the RadColorPicker.